# Help with washing machine installation

Tags: washer

I purchased a washer and dryer from Best Buy and the guys came to install it in my home. They told me they couldn’t finish the installation because they said there’s typically only one drain outlet however my home has two drain outlets.

I spoke with the sales consultant of my neighborhood and she said she’s never been asked that question before and that Best Buy should know how to install it.

Has anyone ever dealt with this before? Does it matter which drain outlet hole I put the hose into?

Thank you!![image][image]

Comment: Are you sure they're both connected to drain pipes? Could be one was knocked out but not piped anywhere...you don't want to drain your washer into the cavity of your wall!

Answer (score 1):

presumably one drain outlet is for a washer and the second is for a condensing dryer, they should be interchangable.

If you're unsure run a test with a glass full of clean water and a funnel

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! You’re right and just found out I can put the hose into either drain outlet.